# Is there a way to use since_id and max_id in Twitter's Search API?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to get the search results between two specific id's but it seems to ignore the ids, here is a sample of my query:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?since_id=58308825907871744&q=%23twitter&rpp=100&max_id=58309448581660674

It just throws back the same set of results if I change the ids. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [search](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search) API doesn't support a `max_id` parameter. It features an `until` parameter instead, which is specified as a date rather than a status ID.  So, you would have to reformat your query something like the following:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?since_id=58308825907871744&q=%23twitter&rpp=100&until=2011-04-14

Twitter API [issue 2052](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=2052) details Twitter's response to the very issue that you raise.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in v1.1 max_id is supported on the search api.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets#api-param-max_id